# Nested loops easy explanation

Tags: loops, nested

I was wondering how to construct nested loops. I have been looking online but have not been able to find any easy to understand explanations! Any help much wanted! ;) XoXo

Comment: Is there a particular language you're using for this?

Answer (score 4):

It only means that one loop is inside another.

For example, if you want to read all characters in SUDOKU which are in 9*9 two-dimensional array.

You create one loop, which iterate through all the rows - from 1 to 9.
If you then create another loop for iterate through columns, also from 1 to 9, for each row the whole nested loop is executed.

Java example :

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Go to the row: " + i );
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println("Accesing : " + i + "/" + j);
        }
    }
```

Have this output :

```
Go to the row: 1
Accesing : 1/1
Accesing : 1/2
Accesing : 1/3
Accesing : 1/4
Accesing : 1/5
Accesing : 1/6
Accesing : 1/7
Accesing : 1/8
Accesing : 1/9
Go to the row: 2
Accesing : 2/1
Accesing : 2/2
Accesing : 2/3
Accesing : 2/4
Accesing : 2/5
Accesing : 2/6
Accesing : 2/7
Accesing : 2/8
Accesing : 2/9
Go to the row: 3
Accesing : 3/1
Accesing : 3/2
Accesing : 3/3
Accesing : 3/4
Accesing : 3/5
Accesing : 3/6
Accesing : 3/7
Accesing : 3/8
Accesing : 3/9
Go to the row: 4
Accesing : 4/1
Accesing : 4/2
Accesing : 4/3
Accesing : 4/4
Accesing : 4/5
Accesing : 4/6
Accesing : 4/7
Accesing : 4/8
Accesing : 4/9
Go to the row: 5
Accesing : 5/1
Accesing : 5/2
Accesing : 5/3
Accesing : 5/4
Accesing : 5/5
Accesing : 5/6
Accesing : 5/7
Accesing : 5/8
Accesing : 5/9
Go to the row: 6
Accesing : 6/1
Accesing : 6/2
Accesing : 6/3
Accesing : 6/4
Accesing : 6/5
Accesing : 6/6
Accesing : 6/7
Accesing : 6/8
Accesing : 6/9
Go to the row: 7
Accesing : 7/1
Accesing : 7/2
Accesing : 7/3
Accesing : 7/4
Accesing : 7/5
Accesing : 7/6
Accesing : 7/7
Accesing : 7/8
Accesing : 7/9
Go to the row: 8
Accesing : 8/1
Accesing : 8/2
Accesing : 8/3
Accesing : 8/4
Accesing : 8/5
Accesing : 8/6
Accesing : 8/7
Accesing : 8/8
Accesing : 8/9
Go to the row: 9
Accesing : 9/1
Accesing : 9/2
Accesing : 9/3
Accesing : 9/4
Accesing : 9/5
Accesing : 9/6
Accesing : 9/7
Accesing : 9/8
Accesing : 9/9
```